# how to set the first column width as Fixed in a GrdiView

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

In a asp.net Grid View, I would like to set fixed width for the first column (it will have static labels) and remaining columns should share equal width. 
Maximum columns displayed in the gridview is 12. I am using TemplateField's in the Grid. 
I tried setting HeaderStyle-Width="12%" ItemStyle-Width="12%" for first column and for remaining columns I set as 8%, but it is not working. Any suggestions please.

```html
<asp:Table ID="Table1" BorderWidth="0" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" Width="100%" runat="server">
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                             <asp:GridView ID="_gridView1" runat="server"  
                                                EnableViewState="false" ShowFooter="false" AllowPaging="false" EnableFixedHeader="true" Width="100%" 
                                                 AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
        
                                                 <Columns>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="12%" ItemStyle-Width="12%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate >
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_LineName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LineName") %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity0" HeaderText="Entity0" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityZero" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName0") %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                         </asp:TemplateField>
                                                         <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity1" HeaderText="Entity1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityOne" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName1") %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                         </asp:TemplateField>
                                                         <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity2" HeaderText="Entity2"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                      <asp:Label ID="_entityTwo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName2") %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity3" HeaderText="Entity3" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityThree" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName3") %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                         <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity4" HeaderText="Entity4" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityFour" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName4")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity5" HeaderText="Entity5" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityFive" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName5")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity6" HeaderText="Entity6" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entitySix" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName6")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity7" HeaderText="Entity7" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entitySeven" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName7")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity8" HeaderText="Entity8" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityEight" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName8")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity9" HeaderText="Entity9" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityNine" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName9")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                      <asp:TemplateField ID="Entity10" HeaderText="Entity10" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="8%">
                                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="_entityTen" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityName10")  %>' />
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    </Columns>
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
```

Comment: Define "not working"? Show the GridView.

Comment: @VDWWD: added GrdiView snippet

Comment: Works fine... Is perhaps some css interfering? And a GridView is already a Table, no need to wrap it with one.

Comment: I think this link would help you: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/two_columns.html

Make changes in the Jquery such that the fixed column is set to one.

Comment: @Rohan: looking into it. thanks.

Comment: @Tim No problem. Did it work?